# How to list culprit users when Jenkins build fails (sending by Slack)

Tags: jenkins

How I can list all culprits users related to the broken builds since the last successful build and the current one?

Besides that, how to compile all this information and then send by Slack?

Answer (score 1):

The script below describes how to configure the post processing step to send culprits users from history of broken builds.

```
#!groovy​

pipeline {

    agent { label 'pipeline-maven'}

    post {
        failure {

            script {
                def userDetailsService = load("get-users-details.groovy")
                env.slack_msg = userDetailsService.getFailedBuildHistory()
            }

            slackSend baseUrl: 'https://xxx.slack.com/services/hooks/jenkins-ci/',
                    channel: '#xxxx',
                    color: 'bad',
                    token: 'aIPJis6V4P9VOpTFhUtCQRRL',
                    message: "Broken build ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}\n${slack_msg}"
        }
    }

}
```

The script below (get-users-details.groovy) is responsible to enumerate all culprits based on the previous broken build history.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def String getFailedBuildHistory() {
    def message = ""
    // Iterate over previous broken builds to find culprits
    def fullName = "pipeline-test"
    def jobData = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(fullName)
    def lastStableBuild = jobData.getLastStableBuild()
    def lastBuildNumber = jobData.getLastBuild().getNumber() - 1 // We subtract the current executing build from the list
    if (lastStableBuild != null && lastStableBuild.getNumber() != lastBuildNumber) {
        def culpritsSet = new HashSet();
        message += "Responsibles:\n"
        // From oldest to newest broken build, since the last sucessful build, find the culprits to notify them
        // The list order represents who is more responsible to fix the build
        for (int buildId = lastStableBuild.getNumber() + 1; buildId <= lastBuildNumber; buildId++) {
            def lastBuildDetails = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(fullName).getBuildByNumber(buildId)
            if (lastBuildDetails != null) {
                lastBuildDetails.getCulpritIds().each({ culprit ->
                    if (!culpritsSet.contains(culprit)) {
                        message += "    ${culprit} (build ${lastBuildDetails.getNumber()})\n"
                        culpritsSet.add(culprit)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
    // Complement the message with information from the current executing build
    if (currentBuild.getCurrentResult() != 'SUCCESS') {
        def culprits = currentBuild.changeSets.collectMany({ it.toList().collect({ it.author }) }).unique()
        if (culprits.isEmpty()) {
            // If there is no change log, use the build executor user
            def name = currentBuild.getBuildCauses('hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause').userName
            message += "    ${name} (current build ${currentBuild.getId()})"
        } else {
            // If there is change log, use the committer user
            culprits.each({ culprit ->
                message += "    ${culprit} (current build ${currentBuild.getId()})"
            })
        }
    }
    return message
}

return [
        getFailedBuildHistory: this.&getFailedBuildHistory
]
```